# How to upgrade mysql 5.7.29 to 5.7.38 without impacting production instance

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Hi I want to upgrade the mysql 5.7.29 to 5.7.38 without impacting  production instance.

Can someone help me with the commands

Comment: To build a replica route from 5.7.29 to 5.7.38, business use vip to access the database. change the vip to slave database with version 5.7.38

Comment: @ElapsedSoul That's a good point. But what if the OP does not have another node to run the new db server? I was thinking of using another instance on the same node. But the tcp port number need to be changed for the new instance. Then the application side will have to make adjustment.

Comment: To use a virtual port for business to access ,then use iptables to foreword the port. hem, what a bad idea.... what ever, business need reconnect to db. why not to take a litter break for the operation.